# D3: How to use colors stocked within the array for slices of pie?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, pie-chart

I am new to d3 and javascript and I am trying to understand how to use colors that are stocked in an array for each slice of a pie chart... I think the problem is the same, but I also cannot seem to find the right procedure to print the text with a reasonnable size in the slice. I have everything in the "donnees" variable.
Here is my code.

```
var canvas2=d3.select(".result-side2")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",500).attr("height",500);

var donnees= [{"name":"PS","chiffre":285, "couleur":"pink"},{"name":"UMP","chiffre":199,"couleur":"blue"}, {"name":"UDI","chiffre":30,"couleur":"steelblue"},{"name":"Ecolo","chiffre":18, "couleur":"green"},{"name":"RRDP","chiffre":17, "couleur":"yellow"}, {"name":"GDR","chiffre":15, "couleur":"red"},{"name":"Non inscrits","chiffre":9, "couleur":"grey"}];
var r= 200;
var p=Math.PI*2;

var group= canvas2.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(r-60)
.outerRadius(r)
/*    .startAngle(1)
.endAngle(p-1)*/;

var pie= d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d){return d.chiffre;});

var arcs= group.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(donnees))
.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

arcs.append("path")
.style("fill", function(d){return d.couleur;})
.attr("d", arc);

arcs.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";})
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d){return d.name});
```

The pie I have in the end is black but with the correct size for each slice. The colour is not right and although the place of the text is fine, I don't think it is correctly appearing.

Thanks a lot.
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups. That's found.
To any use it may be for those who come later with a similar question...

```
arcs.append("path")
.style("fill", function(d,i){return donnees[i].couleur;})
.attr("d", arc);

arcs.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";})
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d,i){return donnees[i].name});
```